# Block properties, attributes and settings

Tags: options, block-editor, customization

Reading the Gutenberg Handbook about the new Block architecture in WordPress, I've come across references to "properties", "attributes" and "settings" for the blocks. As there's a lot to read, I've lost track of what the differences are between them. A top level overview would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

*Settings* is what you define in `registerBlockType()` in the block.js file. Here you have to add most basic settings like title:, category: and icon:. ([Handbook link](https://wordpress.org/gutenberg/handbook/designers-developers/developers/tutorials/block-tutorial/writing-your-first-block-type/#registering-the-block)).  
  
*Attributes* are optional, also in `registerBlockType()`. You can extract values from markup i.e. for saving the block content ([Handbook link](https://wordpress.org/gutenberg/handbook/designers-developers/developers/block-api/block-attributes/)).  
  
*Properties* get passed from the editor. You can find them in the edit: and save: function. Here you can call the optional attributes like 'props.attributes' ([Handbook link](https://wordpress.org/gutenberg/handbook/designers-developers/developers/block-api/block-edit-save/)).  
  
Maybe it's not the best explanation, but I hope you get an idea. ;o)